# How to keep responsive images same height?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a webpage that I'm making, and I have one row with a cover photo and profile picture side-by side. I have them both in a bootstrap row in different-sized grids. But, the profile picture is always extending lower than the cover photo (it's height is larger). How do I keep them responsive, but the same height? My ultimate goal is have them look like a single strip (with padding between), and then stack when window is mobile-sized.

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/851x315" class="img-responsive" alt="Cover Photo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive" alt="Profile Picture">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have tried restricting the height of the row div, setting it to a specific height, and switching up the bootstrap grid to be col-md, or col-sm in different proportions. Any wisdom is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use min-height on them

try

```
img {
min-height:100%
}
```

if that doesn't work use a fixed max-height

```
img {
min-height:4em;
}
```

Comment: it seems to me this solution has issues on different browses (setting image's  width:auto creates large images in IE, width 100% causes stretching of images with different ratios in the same row) unless you set `flex:` of image container to image width/image height. This can be done by preprocessor or php. As here - https://codepen.io/blimpage/pen/obWdgp

Answer (score 4):

You can use following codes.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row cover-row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/851x315" class="img-responsive" alt="Cover Photo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 profile-wrap">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive profile-pic" alt="Profile Picture">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Desktop and Tablet Screens */
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .cover-row {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100px; /* minimum height of cover stripe */
    }
    .profile-wrap {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .profile-pic {
        width: auto; /* maintain width/height aspect ratio */
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

JSFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/feh4ex3p/

Comment: Thanks for responding, but for some reason this didn't work for me. copied your code exactly and I understand it all, but for some reason it's not working at all. Profile picture still extends lower than cover photo

Comment: Above codes only work for screen width 768px and above. Make sure you tested them in such a screen. Notice, In my JSFiddle link, I used `col-xs-8` and I did not use `@media (min-width:768px)`. So it works for all screen sizes. Or, upto cover image/stripe is higher than 99px.

Comment: Yea, I copied the code from the js fiddle and it still fails to line up. Upon inspect element, It looks like the cover photo div is equally matching the height of the profile picture, but the cover photo itself is not.

Comment: Did you call Bootstrap CSS before given CSS codes?
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: Yes, bootstrap is the first stylesheet imported, my custom stylesheet (where I added your code) is the last/most recent

Comment: For a full-width hero image, change the CSS for`profile-pic` to `width: 100%; height: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me, but this did:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row cover-row">
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/851x315" class="img-responsive" alt="Cover Photo">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 profile-wrap">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive profile-pic" alt="Profile Picture">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.profile-pic {
    width: 100%; /* maintain width/height aspect ratio */
    height: 500px; /*I realized this doesnt seem responsive, but no percentages work for me but it appears fine on mobile*/
}
```